# Select columns from nth row out all the rows which contains a value in a column in a SQL table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Below is my table in a database.

What is the SQL query I should run to get 'name' & 'plot_summary' values from the 2nd row of all the rows which contain 'Drama' in 'movie_category' column?

[image]

Note - I have not populated the table completely yet and this is for reference. This table will contain many different rows having different 'movie_category' values and the 'n'th or'i'th row number required will be passed through a parameter in the query.

Comment: i removed `Sql-server` tag cause `Mysql` <> `Sql-server`

Comment: "2nd row" is not a defined statement unless you specify a column which defines that ordering.

Comment: Which movie you want to display: `Newton` or `Taal`? And based on what condition? Kindly explain.

Comment: Is there a AUTO_INCREMENT id or a create_time (DATETIME) column in the table? You need that to determine the row order. at add to @TimBiegeleisen 's comment

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Is this something that can be used? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql 
I have read it but not able to fully understand how to implement it.

Comment: Now I'm really lost...you tagged your question with MySQL/PHP, but the link you pasted is for SQL Server.  Which database are you actually using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Apologies for this. I am quite new to programming. I am using database present in the phpMyAdmin section of my online server which hosts my website.

Comment: If you want the second row, you need to have a column which defines a record as being second.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Harshil For a little perspective, I am using this query to generate a JSON which will display the 'plot_summary' and 'name' on an android app. I am able to pass the position of the item and movie_category name from my app which contains the list of movies 'name' in that 'movie_category' to this query. Hence, I want a particular row (based on the position) from all the rows which contain that 'movie_category'.

Comment: Ok. But the problem is you don't have any column in your table that indicates the position of movie. You should at least add an AUTO INCREMENT column in your table in order to achieve this task.

Comment: Yup, I get it how it can be done that way but then I will have to implement sending 'name' of the movies or row id from the android app code to the query which I was not able to do in the first place. I had figured this query will help me do that. So I'm kind of stuck now.

Comment: You are already passing `position`. What is that?

Comment: @Harshil The position of the view that is clicked in the onItemClick method of OnItemClickListener. The 'name' is put in the listview through getter & setter methods and I have tried but failed to get the String name of the selected item through the getName() method.

Comment: I think there are only 2 ways to achieve this: 1) Add an Auto Increment column in table, maintain same sequence in listview in your app as it's in databse and pass the position/rowid. (2)You already had name of movie in your listview. Pass the movie name as parameter.    I will prefer 1st as having an Id/Primary key will make your life easy in future for all other queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`Select name,plot_summary from TableName where movie_category='Drama'`

You just have to change TableName by your real table name and it will run.
I don't understand why you want the row number. 
is it good?

Comment: I will use this query to get information to my android app through a JSON & thus, I just want one of the rows based on the i or n variable that will be passed.